# do ElasticSearch date_histogram aggregation and wrap results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a lot of timestamps stored as `date` type, and I want to get the histogram in `day` or `hour` but only considering those buckets.

For example, if I aggregation on hour for a time range more than 1 day, I may have results `{ key_as_string: 2017-01-01-11-00, doc_count: 111 }` and `{ key_as_string: 2017-01-02-11-00, doc_count: 222 }`, because their keys are different. Even if I'm only interested in `hour` and use `format: "HH"` in aggregation, it still returns 2 entries in `buckets`.

It there any built-in way I could directly get `{ key_as_string: 11, doc_count: 333 }` as result from ES?

update:

sample mapping

```
{
  "index1": {
    "type1": {
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sample query

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "hr": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "format": "HH",
        "interval": "hour",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your query?

Comment: sample query added

Comment: can you also share sample docs to understand your format for timestamps

Comment: it's `date` data type

Comment: yes, that's why i asked as i am getting proper result using "aggregations": {
    "hr": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "15",
          "key": 1488812400000,
          "doc_count": 28
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "16",
          "key": 1488816000000,
          "doc_count": 14
        }
      ]
    }
  }

Comment: but the result I want is only consider `key_as_string` and `doc_count`, ignore difference of `key`s

Comment: I found this article is doing exactly what I want  https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-aggregations-weekday-hourly-analysis , now I need to find how to do this in query....